# How to easily get vaadin testbench queries?

Tags: java, vaadin

I've seen that vaadin testbench adds an extension of the `By` class available in selenium that allows you to do `By.vaadin()` which in theory is more awesome than the selenium counterparts.

The only problem I'm having is...how do I (or more specifically a tester) construct a query that is readable by `By.vaadin()`? For selenium you use the selenium IDE where you can point at an element, how do you do the same for vaadin?

I've started the application in debug mode but the console seems to generate java code:

```
ButtonElement button1 = $(TabSheetElement.class).id("MainTabSheet")
    .$(HorizontalLayoutElement.class)
    .$$(HorizontalLayoutElement.class).$$(ButtonElement.class).first();
```

According to the documentation (http://vaadin.com/download/book-of-vaadin/current-br/html/testbench.selectors.html) you need a selector in the form of:

```
 "bookexamplestobetested::/VVerticalLayout[0]/ChildComponentContainer[1]/VLabel[0]"
```

So how do you construct such a query? Preferably in a point-and-click kind of way?

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](http://vaadin.com/download/book-of-vaadin/current-br/html/testbench.selectors.html)

> A Vaadin selector begins with a UI identifier. It is the URL path of
>   the UI, but without any slashes or other special characters. For
>   example, /book-examples/tobetested would be bookexamplestobetested.
>   After the identifier, comes two colons "::", followed by a
>   slash-delimited component path to the component to be selected. The
>   elements in the component path are client-side classes of the Vaadin
>   user interfacer components. For example, the server-side
>   VerticalLayout component has VVerticalLayout client-side counterpart.
>   All path elements except the leaves are component containers, usually
>   layouts. The exact contained component is identified by its index in
>   brackets.
>   `bookexamplestobetested::/VVerticalLayout[0]/ChildComponentContainer[1]/VLabel[0]`

However I would reconsider using such detailed selector in your Web Tests as it have many disadvantages. Your tests have hard dependency on name of your UI, structure of your layouts and component hierarchy. Much more flexible approach is to identify items in a way that has no knowledge about position of component in layout hierarchy and refers only to components html element id, unique css class, or maybe location attribute from CustomLayout. This Way your web tests are much simpler and change resistant. When you change your layouts, reorder components or add some more, your tests will not break. So you can use regular WebDriver selectors like `By.ById`, `By.ByClassName` and such.

Comment: I understand how the xpath-like syntax works, what I'm more wondering about is how testers are supposed to figure that out. They have no idea how the vaadin application is built, they just have the website and are used to point & click using selenium. Currently I'm considering a conversion script from the output of the vaadin debug mode point & click to a webdriver-compatible xpath.

Comment: I suppose those vaadin selectors are more suited for cases where developers write web tests as we do in our company. For Your case it is probably best to still use xpath queries as you testers can easily construct those and they already know how to do it.

Comment: The problem is _how_ do the testers construct the XPaths. They know there is a button on the screen. They don't know what combination of vertical layouts and horizontal layouts got it there. They can't build an xpath, all they have is a button on the screen. Ideally there should be an interface that allows you to click on that button and that generates the xpath. This exists in debug mode but it generates java code, not xpath.

Comment: I thought you said you use selenium ide for constructing xpath queries? Alternatively your testers can try easy to use browser add-ons for getting xpath to elements such as this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl

Comment: I meant they use selenium for selenium XPath queries. I wonder how they are supposed to build vaadin xpath queries. The whole idea of vaadin testbench is that it is more stable than selenium with regards to vaadin applications as you don't have to select 25 divs to get to a position but instead use logical elements. But even the path of such logical elements is too much to ask for a tester to construct.

Comment: Well, the question is whether you really want to use them. Testbench has benefits on its own like waiting for components to be ready and such. So you can still have this advantages while using standard webdriver selectors.

Comment: As i said in my posti would reccomend selecting by component id which is unique. Your tests wont break if you change your layouts and they are as simple as it can get to construct - By.Id("ComponentId"). It should be very easy to construct even for testers.

Comment: Yes, I agree that is a good approach but there is already a massive codebase that doesn't use it properly at the moment.